# Unable to create hotspot using network-manager of Gnome /Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, wifi-hotspot

I'm unable to create a hotspot using network-manager of Gnome.
By click on `use as hotspot`-> `Turn on`, nothing is happening; I don't get any pop up telling created, failed, etc. No config files regarding hotspot are being created in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connection` either. I have installed almost all optional dependencies of networkmanager except for `bluez` and `ppp`.
The device I'm using is TP link TL-WW722N.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap):

```
pacman -S create_ap

sudo create_ap -m bridge wifi_interface ethernet_interface test_arch vinod123
```

Note: You won't be able to browse internet on the host. Maybe we should use NAT rather than bridge. I haven't tried it yet to confirm anything regarading NAT.

**UPDATE**

Used NAT and I'm able to browse on the host too.

```
sudo create_ap -m nat wifi_interface ethernet_interface test_arch vinod123
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good script, works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The failure is probably due to this Gnome control-center bug:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1399693

A workaround is to set a valid pretty-hostname with command:

```
hostnamectl --pretty set-hostname $(hostname)
```